# Convert json to csv but break subitem into there own line using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, csv

Good day, I'm trying to convert json data into a csv file. Currently when the csv file is generated it does not place items with child onto their own line.

Below is a diagram of how the data should appear within the csv file.

```
┌──────────────┬───────────────────────┬───────────────────┬──────────────┬────────────┐
│     Name     │    Social Packages    │   Product Title   │ Product Cost │ Total Cost │
├──────────────┼───────────────────────┼───────────────────┼──────────────┼────────────┤
│ Bruce Lee    │ None                  │ Sample title      │         2500 │      17100 │
│              │ None                  │ Another title     │          600 │            │
│              │ None                  │ Yet another title │        14000 │            │
│ Superman     │ 12 Week Starter       │ None              │            0 │       2215 │
│ Batman       │ 26 Week Premium       │ Sample Title      │         4500 │       6758 │
│ Wonder Woman │ 123 Marketing Starter │ Title name        │            0 │       4575 │
│              │ 26 Starter            │ None              │         2500 │       8750 │
└──────────────┴───────────────────────┴───────────────────┴──────────────┴────────────┘
```

This a sample of the data im currently working with

```
[
   {
      "Name": "Bruce Lee",
      "SocialPackages": ["None", "None", "None"],
      "ProductTitle": ["Sample title", "Another title", "Yet AnotherTitle"],
      "ProductCost": [2500, 600, 1400],
      "TotalCost": 17100
   },
   {
      "Name": "Bruce Lee",
      "Social Packages": ["None"],
      "ProductTitle": ["Sample title"],
      "ProductCost": [2500],
      "TotalCost": 4580
   },
   {
      "Name": "Bruce Lee",
      "SocialPackages": ["None", "None", "None"],
      "ProductTitle": ["Sample title", "Another title", "Yet AnotherTitle"],
      "ProductCost": [2500, 600, 1400],
      "TotalCost": 17100
   }
]
```

This is the functions i'm using to format the data into a user friendly version.

```
function convertToCSV(objArray) {
   var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
   var str = '';
   for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         var line = '';
         for (var index in array[i]) {
         if (line != '') line += ','

         line += array[i][index];
         }
         str += line + '\r\n';
   }
   return str;
}

function exportCSVFile(headers, items, fileTitle) {
   if (headers) {
      items.unshift(headers);
   }
   // Convert Object to JSON
   var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(items);
   var csv = convertToCSV(jsonObject);
   var exportedFilenmae = fileTitle + '.csv' || 'export.csv';

   var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
   if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
         navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, exportedFilenmae);
   } else {
      var link = document.createElement("a");
      if (link.download !== undefined) {

         var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
         link.setAttribute("href", url);
         link.setAttribute("download", exportedFilenmae);
         link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
         document.body.appendChild(link);
         link.click();
         document.body.removeChild(link);
      }
   }
}

function download(){
   var headers = {
      userName: 'Name',
      socialPackages: "Social Packages",
      productTitle : "Product Title ",
      poroductCost: "Product Cost",
      totalCost: "Total Cost"
   },
   itemsFormatted = [],
   fileTitle = 'Export';

   // format the data
   campaignData.forEach((item) => {
      itemsFormatted.push({
      userName: item.userName,
      socialPackages: item.socialPackages,
      productTitle: item.productTitle,
      poroductCost: item.poroductCost,
      totalCost: item.totalCost
      });
   });

   // call the exportCSVFile() function to process the JSON and trigger the download
   exportCSVFile(headers, itemsFormatted, fileTitle);
}
```

Any pointer on how to modify the convertToCSV function to place the items with child onto a new line would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your json is not in correct format.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON data has some problem. In second JSON Object there is a space in "Social Packages". If that is corrected then the below code can be used to generate CSV as required.

```
function convertToCSV(objArray) {console.log(objArray)
    var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var line = '';
        for (var index in array[i]) {
            if (line != '') line += ','
            line += array[i][index];
        }
        str += line + '\r\n';
    }
    return str;
}

function exportCSVFile(headers, items, fileTitle) {
    if (headers) {
        items.unshift(headers);
    }
    // Convert Object to JSON
    var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(items);
    var csv = convertToCSV(jsonObject);
    var exportedFilenmae = fileTitle + '.csv' || 'export.csv';

    var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, exportedFilenmae);
    } else {
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        if (link.download !== undefined) {
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.setAttribute("href", url);
            link.setAttribute("download", exportedFilenmae);
            link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        }
    }
}

function download(){
    var headers = {
        userName: 'Name',
        socialPackages: "Social Packages",
        productTitle : "Product Title ",
        poroductCost: "Product Cost",
        totalCost: "Total Cost"
    },
    itemsFormatted = [],
    fileTitle = 'Export';

// format the data
campaignData.forEach((item) => {console.log(item)
    if (item.SocialPackages.length == 1) {
        itemsFormatted.push({
            userName: item.Name,
            socialPackages: item.SocialPackages,
            productTitle: item.ProductTitle,
            poroductCost: item.ProductCost,
            totalCost: item.TotalCost
        });
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < item.SocialPackages.length; i++) {
            var itemName = ' ';
            var itemCost = ' ';
            if(i == 0) {
                itemName = item.Name;
                itemCost = item.TotalCost;
            }
            itemsFormatted.push({
                userName: itemName,
                socialPackages: item.SocialPackages[i],
                productTitle: item.ProductTitle[i],
                poroductCost: item.ProductCost[i],
                totalCost: itemCost
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thank you very much it does exactly what expected.